# How to distribute percentage across multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I would like to have 'n' sliders that share 100%, initially I have data like this:

```
<input type="number" id="a" min="0" max="100" value="60"/>
<input type="number" id="b" min="0" max="100" value="30"/>
<input type="number" id="c" min="0" max="100" value="10"/>
```

So if #a decreases from 60% to 40% I want #b and #c to increase 10% each. is there a known algorithm to distribute percentage without overwriting the previous values of #b and #c?

Here's a non working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmrgkn0r),
and a working [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/svmp7eco).

Comment: Describe how `#a` can decrease to `40%` of width

Comment: Your example does not correspond with what you say you want to do. Adding 10% to each of 30% and 10% does not preserve the ratio between them. 40/20 != 30/10.

Comment: If you want to keep the ratio of the privious values, #b and #b should decrease to 20% and 7% respectively. Which do you want, to share 100% or to keep ratio?

Comment: Oh, sorry; nope, not to maintain ratio, but to actually 'share' 100%, if #a goes from 60% to 40%, that freed 20% should be applied equally to #b and #c (10% each).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow keep reference of what the previous total amount was before the change. You could have a data value attached to each input element, but as you always roll back to even 100 distributed between the inputs, it's quite handy to just use that for reference like this:

```
var val_change = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++) {
    val_change -= parseFloat($(sliders[i]).val());
}
```

The codes loops through all inputs and subtracts the amount from the initial 100. If you press the up-key in the input field, this will return `-1` ie. Dividing this number with number of inputs, besides the active one, gives you the amount you need to remove from the other inputs. This calculation replaces your delta calculations.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmrgkn0r/2/

You might want to make a check that none of the inputs reaches 0 or 100, and do something about that.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing the references and unsuccessfully tried to recover them inside the loop; your answer works perfectly, Thanks!